# Python: How do you get an XML element's text content using xml.dom.minidom?

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I've called `elems = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('myTagName')` on an XML object that I parsed as `minidom.parse(xmlObj)`. Now I'm trying to get the text content of this element, and although I spent a while looking through the dir() and trying things out, I haven't found the call yet. As an example of what I want to accomplish, in:

`<myTagName> Hello there </myTagName>`

I would like the extract just "Hello there". (obviously I could parse this myself but I expect there is some built-in functionality)

Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try like this:

```
xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('myTagName')[0].firstChild.nodeValue
```

Comment: I was going to, but it said I needed to wait X minutes before I could since your reply was so prompt :) Done!

Answer (score 8):

wait a mo... do you want ALL the text under a given node?  It has then to involve a subtree traversal function of some kind.  Doesn't have to be recursive but this works fine:

```
    def get_all_text( node ):
        if node.nodeType ==  node.TEXT_NODE:
            return node.data
        else:
            text_string = ""
            for child_node in node.childNodes:
                text_string += get_all_text( child_node )
            return text_string
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for elem in elems:
    print elem.firstValue.nodeValue
```

That will print out each myTagName's text.

James

Comment: Nice, that looks great too, I will try this. Thanks!